# Batch Unable to echo for loop variable if findstr fails

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, findstr

I am trying to create a string that searches for each line in a text file and if there is a match it does nothing but if it finds a line without a match it echoes to an output text file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (C:\listtocheck.txt) do (
    findstr /i %%a C:\master.txt
    if %errorlevel%==1 (echo !%%a! >> "c:\results.txt")
    )
```

I have no idea how I can make this work, and cant find any good working examples to reference to.

```
MASTER FILE
KB3216916   
KB3214051  
KB4012373


LISTTOCHECK FILE
HotFixID   
KB2849697  
KB2849696  
KB2841134  
KB2670838
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please confirm your intent. You have a list of content in a text file of unknown structure and format, `C:\listtocheck.txt` and you have another text file `C:\master,txt` which you intend to check for matches of the strings from the first file. For your output file, `c:\results.txt`; are you wanting to return every string not found in the entire file, every string not found on every line, every string which doesn't match an entire line, or something completely different. It would also help if you provded an example showing the content and structure of both files.

Comment: You'd need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for `ErrorLevel`. Alternatively, use this: `findstr /I "%%a" "C:\master.txt" || (>> "C:\results.txt" echo !%%a!)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your batch work you could use instead of `if %errorlevel%==1`:

1. `if errorlevel 1` see [if /?](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
2. `if !errorlevel!==1` see [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

But I suggest using [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) instead. Changed pathes to current directory.

```
@echo off
Type Nul > results.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (listtocheck.txt
) do findstr /i "^%%a" master.txt >Nul 2>&1 ||(>>"results.txt" echo %%a)
Type results.txt
```

Another simpler way is to use the findstr's /V + /G options which reverses the order:

```
> findstr /i /V /G:Master.txt LISTTOCHECK.txt >results.txt
```

Sample output of results.txt:

```
HotFixID
KB2849697
KB2849696
KB2841134
KB2670838
```

Comment: That would only be necessary if `%%a` represents a variable name and you want to get the content of that variable. Delayed expansion is needed when you set a var in a (code block) / on the same line and want to get the actual value. I'll edit my answer.